# Sorting Dynamic Tables With Input Boxes in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've made a demo of what I'm trying to do here in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/clowerweb/SbNdb/

Just click on the table headers to sort (you may need to click more than once!)

So what I have here is a dynamic table for adding and removing contest entrants who can have a variable number of entries (eventually it'll be savable as well, and choose a random winner).

I figured the users who are inputting contestants might also like to be able to sort the list alphabetically, or by their number of entries. I found a nice table sorter script here on SO, and added it to my jQuery functions.

**Problem is**, it doesn't appear to be reading the input values. It will reverse the order of the table both ways and restore it to default, but it won't actually **sort** them by input values.

**It could be one of two issues:**

1. most likely is that it's simply not reading the input values.
2. It could also not be able to actually see the dynamically added rows
   (although it looks like it loops through the table on click, so I
   don't suspect that as the issue.)

Any help is *greatly* appreciated, and thanks!

Comment: Yo, and the issue is bruv? it doesnot randomise it inverses the rows top to bottom and then bottom one to top: `inverse ? -1 : 1` if you looking for something closer - checkout flexigrid or add table sorter sorting functionality on the added rows, hope this help bruv.

Comment: @Tats_innit The issue is that, if you add a few rows and put something in, like `aaa, ddd, ccc, bbb` in the `Name:` fields, it won't sort them alphabetically. Similarly, it should also have the ability to sort by the number of entries - try making 5 rows, and inputting `1, 5, 3, 2, 4` in the `Entries:` fields. It won't sort them by number. Just click the bolded table headings after making a few fields and inputting the above and see what it does. It's not reading the values that were input into the `input` boxes.

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/MwxXj/5/ . Though it seems not  to work sometimes.

Comment: @joy set it as answer man; yes this works for me!

Comment: @Joy - AWESOME! It seems to be working for me every time. See if you can find the problem you were having, and submit this as an answer and I will accept it! :D

Comment: I dont have much time now, I will test more when I will be able to find time and let you know if I find that condition again or maybe I got it wrong in an earlier version. Thanks. Let me know If you find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are getting in the `comparator function` is the `td`, so to sort based on the `input` you need to search them inside that `td` and and compare with `text field's values`. So the comparator function will look like

```
function(a, b) {                
   return $(a).find('input').val() > $(b).find('input').val() ?
                 inverse ? -1 : 1
                : inverse ? 1 : -1;
}
```

[Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/joycse06/MwxXj/5/)